# How to compare two xmls

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file which looks like the below example

```
<Ids>
   <Id>
      <set>ai</set>
      <idN>2000</idN>
      <Desc>Node</Desc>
      <tabs>
         <tab>
            <tabName>na</tabName>
            <tabAlias>na</tabAlias>
            <tabQualifier>SCH</tabQualifier>
         </tab>
      </tabs>
      <cls>
         <cl>
            <cName>def</cName>
            <cLName>term</clName>
            <clPos>0</clPos>
            <tabName>nodeassign</tabName>
            <clType>C</clType>
            <dName></dName>
            <dI>
               <dB>0</dB>
               <gd>0</gd>
               <gdgR></gdgR>
               <gCol></gCol>
            </dI>
         </cl>
         <cl>
            <cName>default</cName>
            <cLName>mux_id</cLName>
            <clPos>1</clPos>
            <tabName>nodeassign</tabName>
            <clType>I</clType>
            <dName></dName>
            <dI>
               <dB>0</dB>
               <gd>0</gd>
               <gdgR></gdgR>
               <gCol></gCol>
            </dI>
         </cl>
      </cls>
   </Id>
</Ids>
```

This is just a part of a large xml file. I have to compare two xml files and should be able to get out all the differences in two files to an separate xml. Should be able to change the values of few elements if they are different from the other xml file.

So to start with this I followed the approached suggested in the following link http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/46345. But when I have generated a dataset for the given xml, there lots of tables created with in the dataset (like Ids, id, cls, cl, di, tabs...). I did not understand how to establish the relationships between the tables. Also did not understand which column in the generated tables becomes the primary key so that i can rely on it. The example provided in the above link is a simple xml so the author was able to solve the problem easily.

But the xml which I have is bit complex. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Xmldiffpatch. It's a library for diffing Xml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Comment: If suppose <cName>def</cName> is different in one xml file from the another one, can I change the value using this library?

Comment: At what level do you want the diffs at? Say `<dB>0</dB>` is different one one file, would you just want that as a diff or would you want all of its parent nodes with their siblings and children?

Comment: If the value is different at <dB>0</dB> and even at its parent level then I want this whole node to be there in the separate xml. More important than this is, if the values of <cl> are different in the other xml and also having the <cname> as "def" then I should be able to rename it to some other name in the other xml. May be if i am able to achieve this my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed similar solution specified in the given link and was able to solve my problem. But I am still working on it.

When I have created a dataset and loaded my xml, the following relations are created in the dataset and with those I was able to navigate other rows. The relations that were created are as follows:

```
Ids_Id
Id_tabs
tabs_tab
Id_cls
cls_cl
```

The sample code for that is as follows:

```
public void CompareXml()
{
    DataSet xml1DS = new DataSet("Xml1");
    DataSet xml2DS = new DataSet("Xml2");   
    DataSet outputDS = new DataSet("Output");       

    //read in our files
    try
    {
        xml1DS.ReadXml(@"C:\xml1.xml", XmlReadMode.Auto);
        xml2DS.ReadXml(@"C:\xml2.xml", XmlReadMode.Auto);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    outputXML = xml2DS;

    IEqualityComparer<DataRow> comparer = DataRowComparer.Default;

    foreach (DataRow row1 in xml1DS.Tables["Id"].Rows)
    {
        bool hasRow = false;
        foreach (DataRow row2 in xml2DS.Tables["Id"].Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)row1["idN"] == (string)row2["idN"])
                {
                    DataRow[] Child1 = row1.GetChildRows("Id_cls")[0].GetChildRows("cls_cl");
                    DataRow[] Child2 = row2.GetChildRows("Id_cls")[0].GetChildRows("cls_cl");

                    foreach (var v in Child1)
                    {
                        foreach (var t in Child2)
                        {
                            //string str = v.GetParentRow("columns_column").GetParentRow("configId_columns")["idNumber"].ToString();


                            if ((v["clPos"].ToString() == t["clPos"].ToString()) &&
                                (v["cLName"].ToString() == t["cLName"].ToString())
                                )
                            {
                                hasRow = true;

                                if (IsColumnNodeEqual(v, t) == false)
                                {
                                    t["cName"] = "###";
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
            }

        }

        if(!hasRow) 
        {

        }
    }

    //write it to the xml file
    outputXML.WriteXml("newXML.xml");

 }
```

Even though the approach is inefficient but I have got easy to extend and maintainable code. Any how this code is just for writing a tool for one of my xmls.